# mySQL index and preparing state

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I get a complicate query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT Transaction 
FROM table1 
WHERE 
Transaction IN (SELECT Transaction FROM table2 WHERE Plugin='XXX' AND Server='XXX') 
AND 
Transaction NOT IN (SELECT Transaction FROM table1 WHERE Detail IN ('Monitor','Version','monitor','version')) 
ORDER BY Date DESC, Millisecond DESC LIMIT 10) 
AS res
```

I get indexes on table1:Detail and the "Transaction" is the primary key of `table2`.

It will take a while(5-10 secs) for the database to return result. So I create another index on table2:Plugin, the query is fasted now, but a preparing state shows up and also takes 5-10 secs. So after I create a new index, the time does not change at all.

Can someone tell me what`s going on and how can I optimize this query? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not simply rewrite the query as follows:

```
SELECT  a.Transaction 
  FROM  table1 a
    INNER JOIN table2 b ON b.Transaction = a.Transaction
  WHERE (b.Plugin='XXX' AND b.Server='XXX')
        AND a.Detail NOT IN ('Monitor','Version','monitor','version')
ORDER BY a.Date DESC, a.Millisecond DESC LIMIT 10
```

So you join the `table2` (which will be faster) and remove all the subqueries.

This should be much faster.

Comment: Actually what I thought before is it will be faster if I do the select before join, is it correct?